# fill opacity and \end{document}

Tags: tikz-pgf

If document is ended normally
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red,fill opacity=.2](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If the document is ended using `\stop`, fill opacity is different:
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red,fill opacity=.2](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\stop
```

I am curious why the difference. Can I add something before \stop so that the fill opacity is correct? Thanks for reading!

Comment: well you are missing various pdf object that are written in \end{document}. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the ExtGState object?

Comment: In reply to "Why do you want to do that?" I'm just curious about why fill opacity is written in \end{document}  :)

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ulrike Fischer's comment, I find that adding the line `\pdfpageresources` after the first or the second line will set the fill opacity to 0.2.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}% add after the second line:
\pdfpageresources{/ExtGState <</pgf@ca.2 <</ca 0.2>>>>}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red,fill opacity=.2](0,0)rectangle(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\stop
```

If change `<</ca 0.2>>` to other value (like `<</ca 0.7>>`) the fill opacity will change accordingly.

It won't take effect if \pdfpageresources is added after \begin{tikzpicture}
Also won't take effect if \pdfpageresources is added before \documentclass

But can we use a command to let TikZ write to /Resources?

Comment: This will break as soon as you have two or more opacity settings (and it won't work in other engines). Why don't you let tikz handle its resource management? Asking for help how to willingly break working code doesn't look very sensible.